# Passing glUniform functions as parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am currently writing a openGL shader class. Instead of heaving functions to set each uniform type, i'm trying to pass the uniform function (eg. glUniform1f) as a parameter.

my current try looks something like this:

```
template <typename T1> 
void Shader::setUniform(void (* fnc)(GLint, T1), const GLchar *name, const T1 value1)
{
    fnc(getUniformLocation(name), value1);
}
```

called with

```
shader.setUniform<GLfloat>(*glUniform1f, "test", 5);
```

however, I'm constantly getting conversion errors like:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__stdcall *)(GLint,GLfloat)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(GLint,GLfloat)'
```

Is it possible to get this working as intended?

Thanks

Note: I'm using GLEW and glfw if this is important

Comment: I am not familiar with openGL but have you tried passing the function via a `std::function` instead of a function pointer?

Comment: Not yet, just a sec.

Comment: A better question would be... why do you want to? Your goal here seems to be having template wrappers for the `glUniform` family of functions. But your way of doing it requires the user to both pass in the type (`GLfloat`) and the function pointer, which... already has the type. There have to be superior ways of doing what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: The basic idea is to have one single function instead of sooo many e.g. void setUniform1f(const GLchar *name, float value); 
   void setUniform1i(const GLchar *name, int value);

Comment: @LevyEhrstein: But you don't *achieve that*. You still have to type the name of the function you're trying to call. The user still has to remember which function they really want to call. You're not hiding the fact that there are "sooo many" functions from the user. So what good is the API?

Comment: Yea, but i think this is simpler than overloading setUniform for i.d.k. how many times. Let's not discuss whether or not this makes sense, but whether or not this is possible. I guess it is, but idk how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function pointers from OpenGL loading libraries (particularly those which return functions loaded directly from the DLL) will sometimes be annotated with a different calling convention from regular function pointers.

Such function pointers are *not* inter-convertible.

There are two ways to handle this. You could use a different OpenGL loading library, one which deals in function pointers that use the standard calling conventions (essentially, hiding the actual pointers it loads). For example, in [my glLoadGen loader](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home), if you use the [`func_cpp`](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_Function_CPP) generator style, all functions will be regular C++ functions.

Otherwise, you will have to change how your function pointer is declared in your interface to match how your loader works. For example, if you're using GLEW, you would have to do something like this:

```
void Shader::setUniform(void (GLAPIENTRY* fnc)(GLint, T1), const GLchar *name, const T1 value1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could templatize function on  functor's type as well, sparing yourself from dealing with function pointer syntax, calling conventions etc. This version will accept everything that can be called with documented arguments (be it function, functional object, lambda etc.). It's the main strength and weakness at the same time. Type restrictions via concepts will hopefully be introduced in next versions of C++ standard.

```
template <typename F, typename T1>
// requires: F callable with parameter types GLint, T1
void Shader::setUniform(F fnc, const GLchar* name, const T1 value1) {
    fnc(getUniformLocation(name), value1);
}

int main() {
    ...
    shader.setUniform(glUniform1f, "foo", 3.14f);
}
```

I agree with comments, that this doesn't really change much, as user still types function name and all parameters.
More "object oriented" approach might be to introduce a templated class for uniforms and to specialize it per argument type (there aren't many).